# How to turn '#Num!' values into zeros

Tags: sql, null, ms-access-2010

I have a query that compiles and runs but some of the field values are '#Num!', how would i let Access know that if the cell contains the error to give me a zero? i tried

`IIF(Column Is Null,0,Column)` but it didnt work.. or maybe i didnt use it properly?

Here is my query

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
       Round(((CDbl(qb1.DatapointValue)/CDbl(qb2.MPPGas))*100),0) AS AnnualSDGAS
FROM PEBaseQuery AS qb1 
INNER JOIN PE_Field_MPPGasRevisedMarketRemoved AS qb2 
    ON (qb1.Year=qb2.Year) 
    AND (qb1.AssetName = qb2.AssetName) 
    AND (qb1.CompanyName = qb2.CompanyName)
WHERE qb1.DatapointID=2035;
```

Comment: `iif(isnumeric(column), column, 0)` should help, but problem should be addressed at point of origination.

Comment: As Nikola Markovinović says, it would be much better to solve the problem than to deal with the symptoms. Otherwise, you are building a new problem for the future.

Comment: thanks ive edited the base query for the calculations to store zeros instead of blanks. If some assets of a company dont have an entry in the base query for a particular datapoint (but the datapoint is used in the calculation), how can i say just put a zero in their results cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[IsNumeric()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnumeric.php)** to check if the value is a number or not.

```
SELECT IIF(ISNUMERIC(columnName), columnName, 0)
FROM ....
```

Example of IsNumeric():

```
IsNumeric (786)                 would return TRUE
IsNumeric ("Tech on the Net")   would return FALSE
IsNumeric ("234")               would return TRUE
```

From your query, i found this line

```
CDbl(qb1.DatapointValue) / CDbl(qb2.MPPGas)
```

careful with this column `qb2.MPPGas` [to avoid dividng by zero error](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/divide_by_zero.php).

---

- I have a question for you, do you store numbers as text (*or string*) in the database?

Comment: And thanks for bringing my attention to qb2.MPPGas you were right about it being a zero in some cases (were i got the '#Error') .. any idea how i could change the code i posted to prevent this?